# I'm getting error 800A03EA with "Else"

Tags: vbscript

The problem is on line fourteen. Else is somehow a syntax error, (800A03EA) I'm very new to VBScript.

```
Dim StrThing, fso, f
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If f.FileExists("Desktop\testfile") then
    StrThing=InputBox("Type your name in")
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("Desktop\testfile.txt", ForWriting, True)
    f.WriteLine "Hello world!" 
    f.WriteLine "Hello, " & StrThing
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("Desktop\testfile.txt", ForReading)
    WriteLineToFile = f.ReadAll
    StrThing=MsgBox("Hello, " & StrThing)
    StrThing=MsgBox("Goodbye, " & StrThing)
    End if
Else
    x=MsgBox("Hello")
    f.createTextFile
    StrThing=InputBox("Type your name in")
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("Desktop\testfile.txt", ForWriting, True)
    f.WriteLine "Hello world!" 
    f.WriteLine "Hello, " & StrThing
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("Desktop\testfile.txt", ForReading)
    WriteLineToFile = f.ReadAll
    StrThing=MsgBox("Hello, " & StrThing)
    StrThing=MsgBox("Goodbye, " & StrThing)
    End if
```

Comment: you have ended `if` statement at line 13. so, `else` will be a syntax error at line 14.

Comment: is your question resolved ? Have you tried [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36818104/5832518) ?

Answer (score 1):

Two changes required here.

1. `else` statement started after closing `if`
2. `f.FileExists` ← No object defined for `f`.

#### Modified code:

```
Dim StrThing, fso, f
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If f.FileExists("Desktop\testfile.txt") then
    StrThing=InputBox("Type your name in")
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("Desktop\testfile.txt", ForWriting, True)
    f.WriteLine "Hello world!" 
    f.WriteLine "Hello, " & StrThing
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("Desktop\testfile.txt", ForReading)
    WriteLineToFile = f.ReadAll
    StrThing=MsgBox("Hello, " & StrThing)
    StrThing=MsgBox("Goodbye, " & StrThing)
Else
    x=MsgBox("Hello")
    f.createTextFile
    StrThing=InputBox("Type your name in")
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("Desktop\testfile.txt", ForWriting, True)
    f.WriteLine "Hello world!" 
    f.WriteLine "Hello, " & StrThing
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("Desktop\testfile.txt", ForReading)
    WriteLineToFile = f.ReadAll
    StrThing=MsgBox("Hello, " & StrThing)
    StrThing=MsgBox("Goodbye, " & StrThing)
End if
```

Comment: I know this is old, but thanks!  This saved me much effort in troubleshooting and identifying the issue!